# laravel, How to route from controller to another resource controller using request object

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have two controllers (Workflow and Stage), I need to route to `Stage.store` function from the `Workflow.store` function using a request object I have been created :

**Workflow controller:**

```
public function store(WorkflowRequest $request)
{
    $oWorkflow = new WfWorkflow();
    $oWorkflow->name = $request->get('workflow_name');
    if($oWorkflow->save()){
        $aStages = $request->get('wf_stage');
        $params = [
            '_token' => $request->get('_token'),
            'wf_id' => $oWorkflow->id,
            'stages' => $aStages
        ];
        $oStageRequestObject = Request::create(url('stage'), 'POST', $params);
    }
}
```

Now, how can i use the Request object `$oStageRequestObject` to route to `stage.store` using POST method ?

- In `stage.store` i need to use form request validation.

Answer (score 2):

```
$params = [
        '_token' => $request->get('_token'),
        'wf_id' => $oWorkflow->id,
        'stages' => $aStages
    ];
```

You want to send this $params variable to  route to stage.store using POST method .

For that you can set session .

For ex.

In Workflow.store method set session like this.

```
Session(['param' => $params]);
```

Now you can access this session in stage.store method using POST method .

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reuse `stage.store` logic, then I would suggest to create `StageService` service class that handles this logic. So `StageController` would look like this:

```
public function store(Requests\StoreStageRequest $request, StageService $stageService)
{
    $stageService->handleRequest($request); // put controller logic to this function

    return redirect('/somewere');
}
```

And then in `WorkflowController` you may manually create `StoreStageRequest` request and pass it to `handleRequest()`:

```
public function store(WorkflowRequest $request, StageService $stageService)
{
    // ...

    $params = [
        '_token' => $request->get('_token'),
        'wf_id' => $oWorkflow->id,
        'stages' => $aStages
    ];

    $oStageRequest = new Requests\StoreStageRequest($params);

    $stageService->handleRequest($oStageRequest);

    // ...
}
```

As for validation, think the only way is to manually create Validator, and pass to it data and rules.

Hope this helps.